WebPartPagesWebService.GetWebPartPage method throwing server was unable to process request. Unable to complete this action
We're attempting to migrate from SharePoint 2013 on-premise to SharePoint Online, but encountered an error related the SharePoint SOAP endpoint listed below:
WebPartPagesWebService.GetWebPartPage(String documentName, SPWebServiceBehavior behavior)
In an attempt to verify that the issue is in fact on the server and related to SharePoint we tried to simply call the endpoint through PowerShell for a specific page:

# Variables
$WebSvcUrl = "" # Example: https://domain.dk/_vti_bin/WebPartPages.asmx
$PageRelativeUrl = "" # Example: sider/default.aspx
 
# Create webservice proxy
$webserviceProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebSvcUrl -UseDefaultCredential
 
# Get namespace and spwebservicebehavior
$autoGeneratedNamespace = $webserviceProxy.GetType().namespace
$SPWebServiceBehavior = New-Object ($autoGeneratedNamespace + ".SPwebServiceBehavior")
 
# Call endpoint
$webserviceProxy.getWebPartPage($pageRelativeUrl, $SPWebServiceBehavior)


But we encounter the following error:

Exception calling "GetWebPartPage" with "2" argument(s): "Server was unable to process request. ---> Kan ikke fuldføre denne handling.
Prøv igen. ---> Kan ikke fuldføre denne handling.
Prøv igen."
At line:1 char:1
+ $client.getWebPartPage("/Sider/default.aspx", [Microsoft.PowerShell.C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException


Update 1
We attempted to run the same script in another SharePoint environment without any issues, so right now we're working with the theory that it's related to the current SharePoint CU and that they need to upgrade the SharePoint farm.
